# SiteWise not consistent in generating metrics for late data

Tags: aws-iot, aws-iot-sitewise

First of all, very nice that SiteWise now allows ingestion of data that is up to 7 days old: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/11/aws-iot-sitewise-now-allows-ingestion-of-data-up-to-7-days-in-past/

And I can confirm that, as long as the late data is less than 7 days old, SiteWise will accept the data. From the SiteWise monitor dashboard, I can see the late sensor data measurements, as well as their transforms, always show up.

However, AWS IoT SiteWise seems not consistent in calculating (or recalculating) related metrics on arrival of late data. In my experiment, sometimes the metrics are generated, while sometimes they are not, as shown in this dashboard:

[image]

Any insight? Thank you.

FYI:

Sometimes the metrics do get generated.

Before ingesting late data, notice that there is no data between 13:37:09 and 14:00:00

[image]

After ingesting late data, we can see that SiteWise accepts the data and recognises the lateness of the data, the metrics are generated.

[image]